# Major Active Exception while accessing creating user : Exception 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007EF, data 0, 1 access points" [extended Error 8235]

Tags: active-directory, directory, ldap, directoryservices

I need to read the Active Directory, search users and create user functionality.

I am able to use DirectoryEntry in C# and Domain is only physical server.

In my production environment, I have two physical domain servers with same domain name. When I try to search the AD user or create, I am getting the following exception.

> Exception  :  "0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007EF, data 0, 1 access points" [extended Error 8235]

Note that I have Domain Admin privileges on the domain but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Please post the code you're using as well as the Windows version (and service pack) of the DCs throwing the error.

Comment: Windows version is : Windows 7 (Ultimate) version- 6.1(Build 7600) .   Active Directory is on Windows Server version : Windows 2008 R2. The Issue is the we have 2 physical servers with same domain name. ( If there is only one physical domain server issue will not reproduce.). Please help to resolve issue.

Comment: @Vivek were you ever able to resolve this? We are hitting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

0000202B: could mean wrong DN/searchbase like incorrect DC value etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem looks like a DNS problem. I know writting that, I've got statisticaly 80% chance being right. Check the domain name resolution from your client. Check your DNS and verify that your two domain controlers are well registered.

Comment: For your information. i am able to Ping to two domain controllers by IP address and by name also. There is no connectivity /DNS issue. So not sure what is the real cause for this issue. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Of course you can ping, this not means that your DNS is well configured. Can you ping the full DNS name ? Are adressing the Active-Directory DNS for that ? Are the Active-Directory entries in the DNS well configured? If all that is OK can you show your code ?

Comment: The DCDIAG log shows "NtFrs Service" failed DFS sync in domain server. 

Want to know "NtFrs Service"must be running?.

Also the error message like  " ...Failed test VerifyReferences".

Note: I kept details dcdiag log at link

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=456615f0f9cf75b6&sc=documents&uc=2&id=456615F0F9CF75B6%21126

As this is critical please help me to resolve issue quickly.

vivek

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is referall related:

ERROR_DS_REFERRAL
8235 (0x202B)
A referral was returned from the server.

You can find the error codes linked at this [MSDN Article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681390%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I know the error code down vote accept
 

The error you are getting is referall related:

ERROR_DS_REFERRAL 8235 (0x202B)  mentioned at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681390%28VS.85%29.aspx    \n Question is how to resolve this issue.   As i mentioned above my C# application connect to AD server which is only one Physical DC then everything works fine.                                         \n

Comment: In my production environment i have 2 physical servers DC's when i connect to this production environment DC then  i am getting ERROR_DS_REFERRAL 8235 (0x202B) A referral was returned from the server. May be some referral setting is missing in DC's , any one know how to check and solve this issue.
Pls help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi All,

Any update on this please as this very critical for me.

I have kept the DCGIAG log for both Primary and secondary domain servers at below public shared path.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=456615f0f9cf75b6&sc=documents&uc=2&id=456615F0F9CF75B6%21126
Please help to resolve the issue.
Regards,

vivek